# LaTeX: Finding width of a given text and adding a horizontal space of that width

Tags: latex, space, mbox

I would like to add a white space of exactly the width of a given text. I could use `\hspace{}`, but then I need the width that given piece of text is going to use in my LaTeX document.

Another idea is to create an invisible box containing the text. Like `\mbox{text}`, but invisible. As I am pretty sure that I cannot just tell LaTeX not to print that particular box, I am sure that there is another solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, there now also is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You’re searching for `\hphantom` which creates a horizontal phantom box:

```
\par Here is some text
\par \hphantom{Here is some} more text.
```

Will result in something like this:

```
Here is some text
             more text
```